# Zoomable treemap without svg Angular2

Tags: javascript, treemap

I am trying to implement a zoomable treemap which is div based and not svg for an angular project.

This is how far I have reached:

Html File: treemap.html

```
<div class="treemapContainer">
<div class="treemap"
     #treemapContainer>
<div *ngFor="let box of boxes"
     (click)="onBoxClick(box, $event)"
     [style.left.px]="box.x0"
     [style.top.px]="box.y0"
     [style.width.px]="box.width"
     [style.height.px]="box.height"
     [style.background]="box.data.color || defaultColor"
     [class.box--clickable]="box.data.hasChildren && drill"
     class="box"
     [@treemapAnimation]="animate"
     #treemapBox>
  <ng-container #containers></ng-container>
</div>
</div></div>
<ng-template #boxDefaultTemplate
         let-data="data">
 <div class="template"
   title="{{data.name}}">
  <h4 class="template__title">{{data.name}}</h4>
 </div>
</ng-template>
```

.scss file --> treemap.scss

```
.treemapContainer {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.treemap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  &--clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  &.dftm__box-expanded {
    ~ .dftm__box {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      display: none;
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

.ts file --> treemap.ts

import { treemapAnimation } from './treemap.animation';

```
@Component({
 selector: 'treemap',
 templateUrl: 'treemap.html',
 styleUrls: ['treemap.scss'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
 animations: [treemapAnimation]
})
export class DfTreemap implements OnChanges, OnInit {

 //Just pasting relevant content
 /**
  * Re-renders the chart if the data input changes
  * @param {SimpleChanges} changes - changes detected object
  */
  ngOnChanges( changes: SimpleChanges ) {
   if (changes.hasOwnProperty('data') && this.data) {
    this.initData(this.data);
    this.animate = 'levelDown';
    this.goTo(this._data[0].id);
   }
 }

 /**
 * @hidden
 * Initializes the _data array, renders the root node of the tree and then 
  subscribes for possible window resize events
 */
 ngOnInit(): void {
   if (this.data) {
     this.resize.onWindowResize.subscribe(() => this.reRender());
     this.treemapContainerElement = this.treemapContainer.nativeElement;
     this.onMouseEnter = this.renderer.listen(this.treemapContainerElement, 
      'mouseenter', () => {
     this.mouseEnterHandler();
   });
  }
}

//Code to drill down to child level  
goTo( id: string ): void {
const node = this._data.find(item => item.id === id);

if (this.boxes) {
  const currentId = this.boxes[0].parent.data.id;
  if (id === currentId) {
    return;
  }
}

console.log(node);
this.boxes = this.getBoxes(node);
console.log(this.boxes[0].parent);
this.createBreadcrumbs(this.boxes[0].parent.data.name, 
this.boxes[0].parent.data.id,);
this.nodeChanged.emit(node);
this.cdr.detectChanges();
this.embedTemplates(this.containers, this.boxTemplate || 
this.boxDefaultTemplate, this.boxes);
}

//Code to render the parent of current child
goUp(): void {
 const idParent = this.boxes[0].parent.data.idParent;

 if (idParent !== null) {
  this.animate = 'levelUp';
  this.goTo(idParent);
 }
}

onBoxClick( box: DfTreemapBox, event ): void {
if (this.drill && box.data.hasChildren) {
  this.animateTarget(event.target);
  this.animate = 'levelDown';
  this.goTo(box.data.id);
}
}

private animateTarget(element) {
console.log(element);
let ele = this.getElementToAnimate(<HTMLDivElement>element);
if (ele) {
  this.renderer.addClass(ele, 'dftm__box-expanded');
  this.renderer.setStyle(ele, 'height', '100%');
  this.renderer.setStyle(ele, 'width', '100%');
  this.renderer.setStyle(ele, 'left', '0');
  this.renderer.setStyle(ele, 'top', '0');
}
}

 getElementToAnimate(element) {
 if (element.classList.contains('dftm__box--clickable')) {
  return element;
 } else if (element.classList.contains('dftm__treemap')) {
  return null;
 }

 return this.getElementToAnimate(element.parentElement);
 }
}
```

Animation: is a simple fadeInAnimation

```
export let treemapAnimation = trigger('treemapAnimation', [

state('in', style({opacity: 0})),

  transition('void => *', [
    style({opacity: 0}), 
  //the delay is basically to match expanding of the parent div
    animate('100ms 250ms', style({opacity: 1}))
  ]),
  transition('*=> void', [
    style({opacity: 1}),
    animate('100ms 250ms', style({opacity: 0}))
  ]),
]);
```

What I am currently able to achieve is on the click of the parent element, it expands to container height width but does not give a zoom out effect, but the worst part is I am not able to do zoom in effect on calling goUp method.
To call this code: Use

```
<treemap #treemapSimple
                [data]="simple">
    </treemap>

    {
  name: 'root',
  value: null,
  children: [
    {name: 'app', value: 30, color: DF_COLORS.GREEN, children: [
      {name: 'app.item', value: 60, color: DF_COLORS.RED, children: [
        {name: 'app.item12', value: 25, color: DF_COLORS.AMBER, children: [
          {name: 'assets.item1', color: DF_COLORS.GREEN, value: 60},
          {name: 'assets.item2', color: DF_COLORS.AMBER, value: 30},
          {name: 'assets.item3', color: DF_COLORS.BLUE, value: 10}
        ]},
        {name: 'app.item13', value: 15}
      ]},
      {name: 'app.item2', value: 25},
      {name: 'app.item3', value: 15}
    ]},
    {name: 'assets', value: 15, color: DF_COLORS.YELLOW, children: [
      {name: 'assets.item1', value: 60},
      {name: 'assets.item2', value: 30},
      {name: 'assets.item3', value: 10}
    ]},
    {name: 'env', value: 15, color: DF_COLORS.AMBER, children: [
      {name: 'env.item1', value: 50},
      {name: 'env.item2', value: 25},
      {name: 'env.item3', value: 25}
    ]},
    {name: 'lib', value: 8, color: DF_COLORS.RED},
    {name: 'src', value: 7}
  ]
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
P.S. This is chunk of code from actual code.

Comment: Do you have a live example somewhere? It's a lot of code for people to digest just by reading `chunk of code from actual code`

Comment: @igormilla No I do not have a live example. But you can ask me if anything is missing.